# Angular route act like another route without url change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular-UI router and in my project I have this structure of pages:

```
- Main (/main)
-- Table (/main/table/:userid)
-- Info (/main/info)
-- About (/main/about)
```

In case the user going to the `/main` I want it to act like the user hit the `/main/table/1` without causing url change.

How can I achieve that ?

Here are my states:

```
$stateProvider
.state('main', {
    'url': '/main',
    'templateUrl': '/pages/main.html',
    'controller': 'MainController',
    'resolve': { ... }
})
.state('main.table', {
    'url': '/main/table/:userid',
    'templateUrl': '/pages/table.html',
})
.state('main.info', {
    'url': '/main/info',
    'templateUrl': '/pages/info.html',
})
.state('main.about', {
    'url': '/main/about',
    'templateUrl': '/pages/about.html',
})
```

Comment: Can you add your state configurations?

Comment: Using uirouter, just don't add urls for the substates.

Comment: @BenDiamant States added

Comment: You want a redirection, without changing the url. is the maincontroller in use?

Comment: @BenDiamant how can i do the redirect without changing the url ? And yes the MainController is in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7qXuLe8DY64vw3PCk06k?p=preview). The trick is to reuse the "main.table" stuff directly in the main state.

We can have main state define like this:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      'url': '/main',

      views: {
        '': {
          'templateUrl': '/pages/main.html',
          'controller': 'MainController',
        },
        '@main': {
          'templateUrl': '/pages/table.html',
          'controller': 'TableController',
        }
      }
    })
```

And these are almost unchanged, just the /main is replaced from url, it will be passed by parent.

```
.state('main.table', {
    'url': '/table/:userid',
    'templateUrl': '/pages/table.html',
    'controller': 'TableController',
})
.state('main.info', {
    'url': '/info',
    'templateUrl': '/pages/info.html',
})
.state('main.about', {
    'url': '/about',
    'templateUrl': '/pages/about.html',
})
```

And this would be the controller for table view

```
.controller('TableController', function($scope, $stateParams) {
  $scope.userid = $stateParams.userid || 1;  
})
```

Check it all [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/7qXuLe8DY64vw3PCk06k?p=preview)

The technique used here is: The main state does have two views. One of them is the main - **layout template**. The second is immediately injecting other view into that layout. via absolute naming `'@main'` *(unnamed view in the state main)*

That view (for displaying table) is the same which we use for `main.table` state. We just check, that if there is no param **userid**  - 1 is used

Read more about this multi views here

#### [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

small extract from example snippet:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {
    // This will get automatically plugged into the unnamed ui-view 
    // of the parent state template. Since this is a top level state, 
    // its parent state template is index.html.
    templateUrl: 'contacts.html'   
  })
  .state('contacts.detail', {
    views: {
        ////////////////////////////////////
        // Relative Targeting             //
        // Targets parent state ui-view's //
        ////////////////////////////////////

        // Relatively targets the 'detail' view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.
        // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html
        "detail" : { },            

        // Relatively targets the unnamed view in this state's parent state, 'contacts'.
        // <div ui-view/> within contacts.html
        "" : { }, 

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Absolute Targeting using '@'                      //
        // Targets any view within this state or an ancestor //
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // Absolutely targets the 'info' view in this state, 'contacts.detail'.
        // <div ui-view='info'/> within contacts.detail.html
        "info@contacts.detail" : { }

        // Absolutely targets the 'detail' view in the 'contacts' state.
        // <div ui-view='detail'/> within contacts.html
        "detail@contacts" : { }

        // Absolutely targets the unnamed view in parent 'contacts' state.
        // <div ui-view/> within contacts.html
        "@contacts" : { }

        // absolutely targets the 'status' view in root unnamed state.
        // <div ui-view='status'/> within index.html
        "status@" : { }

        // absolutely targets the unnamed view in root unnamed state.
        // <div ui-view/> within index.html
        "@" : { } 
  });
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was far beyond what i expected from an answer, including the example, link etc. Great Job, you rocks!

Comment: Great to see that sir, enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)

Answer (score 0):

*stateProvider* url property is responsible for browser URL routing mechanism.
*stateProvider* templateUrl property is a html partial view template which is going to render against a particular **state**, in our case it is *main*.

```
$stateProvider
    .state('main', { // **main** is a state.
    'url': '/main', // **/main** is a preferred url you want to set in the browser.
    'templateUrl': '/main/table/1', // **/main/table/1** is a template to be rendered.
    'controller': 'MainController',
    'resolve': { ... }
```

})

Comment: This is not what i was looking for, the template should remain /pages/main.html since its the layout template. Now i just want that /main will be used as /main/table/1 and remain the layout template

Comment: In case the user going to the /main I want it to act like the user hit the /main/table/1 without causing url change. i answered against this question. What are you looking for.